# why doesn't memoization work in this Python code?

Tags: python, memoization

i am following a dynamic programming video. However the memoization for my code is not working. It is not storing any True/False when i print(memo) it is blank. Please advise

```
def cansum(targetsum,numbers):
      memo = dict()
      print(memo)
      # check in memory
      if targetsum in memo:
            return memo[targetsum]
      if targetsum < 0: return False
      if targetsum == 0: return True
      for number in numbers:
            remainder = targetsum - number
            if cansum(remainder,numbers) == True:
                  memo[targetsum] = True
                  return True
      memo[targetsum] = False
      return False


print(cansum(7,[2,3])) #True
print(cansum(7,[5,3,4,7])) #True
```

Comment: Well for starters, every time you call `cansum`, this line `memo = dict()` clears the dict..

Comment: oh ok shifting the memo= dict outside of def works. Thanks

Comment: For reference, this is the video @josephgan is referencing: [Dynamic Programming - Learn to Solve Algorithmic Problems & Coding Challenges | YouTube - freeCodeCamp.org](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oBt53YbR9Kk)

Comment: You aren't passing 'memo' along as an argument to `cansum()` in the recursion (which is how it was done in the video, by defining `cansum` with `def cansum(targetsum, numbers, memo = {})` and then doing the recursive call as `cansum(remainder, numbers, memo)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you might want to do:

```
def cansum(targetsum, numbers):
    memo = dict()

    def cansum_helper(targetsum, numbers):
        # check in memory
        if targetsum in memo:
            return memo[targetsum]
        if targetsum < 0:
            return False
        if targetsum == 0:
            return True
        for number in numbers:
            remainder = targetsum - number
            if cansum_helper(remainder, numbers) == True:
                memo[targetsum] = True
                return True
        memo[targetsum] = False
        return False

    result = cansum_helper(targetsum, numbers)

    print(memo)

    return result


print(cansum(7, [2, 3]))  # True
print(cansum(7, [5, 3, 4, 7]))  # True
```

If you put

```
memo = dict()
```

into recursive function, you are creating one dict for every recursive function, and once the memo is set, the **return** statement follows, so you won't be able to see changes. But what is intended is that you only need one dict for your whole function.